# system API doesn't work in an exe when called from another exe or a batch file

Tags: c++, windows-10

I have an exe, let's name it ABC.exe. There is a system API to run a batch file inside ABC.exe.

```
....
int ret = system("C:\\Test.bat");
if(ret == -1)
   printf("The system API failed");

printf("The ret value is = %d",ret);

....
```

When the ABC.exe is run standalone, the Test.bat file is executed correctly. But when ABC.exe is launched via another batchfile or another application, the Test.bat is not run and the system API returns 1. I am not sure what does the return value of 1 mean here.

Please note that, the above scenario works well in Win7 but not in Win-10. And everything has been opened with Admin privileges.

Please help me in resolving the above query.

Update: 
The system call fails with "dir" command as well.
I tried with other commands like "ipconfig", "winver", these are working fine.

Thanks.

Comment: _"the Test.bat is not run"_ How did you verify this? _"I am not sure what does the return value of 1 mean here."_ [Look it up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=vs-2019)

Comment: "*If command is not NULL, system returns the value that is returned by the command interpreter.*" IOW, it returns what the batch file returns. Also, the string literal `"C:\Test.bat"` needs to be changed to `"C:\\Test.bat"` or `R"(C:\Test.bat)"` since \ is an escape character.

Comment: @Michael This is the remark which is present in the following link:
"If command is not a null pointer, the value returned depends on the system and library implementations, but it is generally expected to be the status code returned by the called command, if supported."
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

Comment: @RemyLebeau even with "\\", I get the same error.